# ASP Custom Server-Side Validation not firing

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've been hitting my head against this for a little bit now with no progress, so I'd would absolutely love it if someone can shed some light...I have an ASP.Net Forms site, I load a jQuery Dialog to have the user enter an ID, do a required field, and expression validator client-side(which are working fine), then I'm trying to verify that against a SQL table server-side. Problem is I can't get the server-side CustomValidator to fire, I've changed it from an actual validation script to just 'set args.IsValid = false', added 'Page.Validate()' to the top of the submit button function, added a break point to the custom validate Sub and from all appearances the validate action isn't executed and the submit function continues as if the entry was valid.

```
// Show the Login Dialog
        <script>
         function showLogin() {
             $("#login-dialog").dialog({
                 height: 380
                 , width: 500
                 , modal: true
                 , buttons: {
                     'Login': {
                         text: "Login"
                         //Login Dialog Login Submit button function
                         , click: function () {
                             $("#<%=LoginSubmit.ClientID()%>")[0].click();
                             return false;
                         }
                     }
                     , 'Register': {
                         text: "Register"
                         //Login Dialog Register Button
                         , click: function () {
                             $("#<%=RegisterButton.ClientID()%>")[0].click();
                             return false;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             });
         };
```

```
<%--Login dialog Div--%>

        <div id="login-dialog" title="Please Login or Register" hidden="hidden">

        <p>If you have already setup an Operator ID you can enter it below, otherwise please register for one.</p>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="LoginOperatorID" ErrorMessage="Operator ID is required." CssClass="field-validation-error" />

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="LoginOperatorID" ErrorMessage="Operator ID must be 4-9 digits" CssClass="field-validation-error" ValidationExpression="[0-9]{4,9}" />

        <table id="LoginTable">
        <tr>
        <td>Operator ID:</td>
        <td><input type="password" runat="server" id="LoginOperatorID" maxlength="9" /></td>

            <asp:CustomValidator ID="LoginSubmitValidator" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" Enabled="true" 
                ErrorMessage="Operator ID does not exist." 
                ControlToValidate="LoginOperatorID"
                OnServerValidate="CheckLoginID" CssClass="field-validation-error" />
            </tr>
        </table><br />
        <input type="button" runat="server" id="LoginSubmit" onserverclick="SubmitLogin" hidden="hidden" causesvalidation="true" />
         <input type="button" runat="server" id="RegisterButton" hidden="hidden" onserverclick="RegisterDialog" causesvalidation="false" />
```

```
'Validate Operator Login Sub
    Protected Sub CheckLoginID(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        args.IsValid = False
    End Sub
```

---

```
    'Submit Operator Login Sub
    Sub SubmitLogin()
            Page.Validate()
       .....
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help, it's greatly appreciated!

***Update:***
It definitely seems to relate to the DIV being in a jQuery dialog, per @ShaiCohen's comment, I removed the hidden attribute from both the login button and the div that's used for the dialog causing the dialog div to show in the page as well, when I use the ASP submit button outside the dialog the validation works fine, when I use the ASP button inside the dialog or use the dialog button, the validation doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like your `LoginSubmit` button is set to be hidden. That may be your problem.

Comment: Curious, what's with the truly odd placement of the commas?

Comment: @ShaiCohen That was the only workaround I could find to execute the server-side script onclick from within the jQ Dialog because an ASP button doesn't work within it, wasn't aware the hidden button would affect validation, I'll look around for a solution.

Comment: @Sparky I guess I can attribute that to lots of T-SQL work before starting this project, it became habit to put commas at the beginning of the row so if I comment out or delete a row I don't have to mess with the commas above/below, and intellisense adds the extra space after the comma in VS.

Comment: So was the hidden button the problem? And, btw, I do the same thing with commas .... :)

Comment: @ShaiCohen No Dice(see the above update), and glad to see I'm not the only odd one :)

Comment: Interesting. It may be a hack, but what if the modal dialog button (`LoginSubmit`) triggers a click on a submit button that is _outside_ of the modal? Let me know if you would like some sample code showing how to do that.

Comment: @ShaiCohen I had tried moving the ASP button out of the Modal DIV and un-hiding prior to un-hiding the whole DIV (I think that's what you're describing) and it had no effect, I need to take care of some other sm stuff right now, but later on today I'm going to see if creating the modal on page load, then just opening it with 'ShowLogin()' somehow fixes it, or I know jQuery can do validation too, never done it but all my current ASP one does is exec a TableAdapter Query passing it the user inputted value, which returns a count(). Thanks for the help and feel free to keep the ideas coming.

Comment: I understand that old habits die hard and code formatting is personal preference.  Just an FYI, the trailing commas have not been deadly since IE 7.  Now, avoiding them is simply a matter of good code formatting practices... ironic.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up abandoning using a jQuery modal, and decided to build a Modal using CSS instead, and have had no issues with the validation working there.